# How to convert rows values into different columns based on the values in a Column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

Scenario:

```
VendorID | OPTFIELD   |  VALUE  |   VDESC
---------+------------+---------+---------------------
7ELEVEN  | CHANNELAP  |   03    | Independents
7ELEVEN  | CUSTGROUP  | Metcash | Metcash
7ELEVEN  | SUBCHANNEL |   ING   | Independent Grocery
```

Solution Required:

```
Vendor_ID | level_2 |  level_2_desc| level_3 |         level_3_dec | level_4 | level_4_desc 
----------+---------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------+--------------
7ELEVEN   |    03   | Independents |   ING   | Independent Grocery | Metcash |      Metcash
```

So I just want to convert the rows into columns depending on a particular scenario which is based on the value of one of the Columns(OPTFIELD)

Example:
 - When `OPTFIELD ='CHANNELAP'` then results corresponding to `'CHANNELAP'` that is `Value` and `VDESC` would appear in different columns as `VALUE` in `level_2` and `VDESC` in `level_2_desc`

So, values in `OPTFIELD` columns is the condition on which `VALUE` and `VDESC` should be moved to different Columns.

```
IF 'OPTFIELD' = 'CHANNELAP'  then level_2(Value) and level_2_desc(VDESC) 
IF 'OPTFIELD' = 'CUSTGROUP'  then level_3(Value) and level_3_desc(VDESC) 
IF 'OPTFIELD' = 'SUBCHANNEL' then level_4(Value) and level_4_desc(VDESC)
```

So, the final result will be 1 row for `VendorID = '7ELEVEN'`

```
VendorID | level_2 | level_2_desc |level_3 |level_3_desc |level_4 |        level_4_desc 
---------+---------+--------------+--------+-------------+--------+-------------------- 
7ELEVEN  |      03 | Independents |Metcash |     Metcash |    ING | Independent Grocery
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case of a [Pivot Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table).

You can do it in standard SQL using the following query:

```
SELECT
    VendorID, 
    max(case when OPTFIELD = 'CHANNELAP'  then VALUE end) AS level_2,
    max(case when OPTFIELD = 'CHANNELAP'  then VDESC end) AS level_2_desc,
    max(case when OPTFIELD = 'CUSTGROUP'  then VALUE end) AS level_3,
    max(case when OPTFIELD = 'CUSTGROUP'  then VDESC end) AS level_3_desc,
    max(case when OPTFIELD = 'SUBCHANNEL' then VALUE end) AS level_4,
    max(case when OPTFIELD = 'SUBCHANNEL' then VDESC end) AS level_4_desc
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    VendorID
ORDER BY
    VendorID ;
```

**Assumption**: `(VendorID, OPTFIELD)` is `UNIQUE` (and probably, the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table). This way, the `max` function will actually take the *only* actual value.

MS SQL server also has a specific [`PIVOT` statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), but the syntax to use is a bit awkard when you want to have *two* different columns from each row:

```
SELECT 
    VendorID, 
    [CHANNELAP]   AS level_2, 
    [dCHANNELAP]  AS level_2_desc, 
    [CUSTGROUP]   AS level_3, 
    [dCUSTGROUP]  AS level_3_desc, 
    [SUBCHANNEL]  AS level_4,
    [dSUBCHANNEL] AS level_4_desc
FROM
(
   SELECT 
       VendorID, OPTFIELD, [VALUE] 
   FROM 
       t
   UNION
   SELECT 
       VendorID, 'd' + OPTFIELD, [VDESC]
   FROM 
       t
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    max(VALUE)
    FOR OPTFIELD IN (CHANNELAP, CUSTGROUP, SUBCHANNEL, dCHANNELAP, dCUSTGROUP, dSUBCHANNEL)
) AS PivotTable;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=da0ce762b03b64efbaaeae070d741477)*

NOTE: I am not sure which of the queries is more efficient. You should experiment yourself with your actual data. The `PIVOT` syntax of MS SQL Server is probably more efficient when you're working with just *one* column to pivot. But your case is not exactly the one this statement was intended for (AFAIK).

Check also

- [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server), for the "typical" PIVOT case;
- [PIVOT on two or more fields in SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenobonn/2009/03/22/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server/), although the case is not exactly yours.
- [TSQL PIVOT multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590799/tsql-pivot-multiple-columns), which is very close to your case, and offers a slightly different alternative